# SQL query with case, when AND cast combined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query but I can't find a answer.

```
select IS_ALT = case when IS_ALT IS NULL THEN Cast(0 as bit) else 1 end as veraltet
From Gemeinde
```

The Problem is I can't give an Alias. In this Case the Alias is `veraltet`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `IS_ALT =` is supposed to be, but you provide an alias with `as`, so:

```
select (case when IS_ALT IS NULL THEN Cast(0 as bit) else 1 end) as veraltet  
From Gemeinde
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are assigning a variable in TSQL, in that case an `@` is missing like this:

```
select @IS_ALT  = cast(case when IS_ALT IS NULL THEN 0 else 1 end as bit) as veraltet  
From Gemeinde
```